# Android layout multiple screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry but i cant understand how i can draw a right picture for the right android phone size.
 I readed the android documentation, and they say for i just think in screen size and density and not in resolution, so what size should have my picture?

For example,if i have a phone with size 1000x400(stupid example),and want a button(40x40) that will be in middle,what size should i do?? 40x40?? But in documention they say for dont look for resolution :\

Im confuse...

ps: The documention link [Android multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll have to realize that although *resolution*, *screen size* and *screen density* are separate attributes, they are still somewhat related. If your button is 40x40 as you mentioned, and that's the size you find looks good in the center on a *hdpi*(high density) device, you will have to scale it so that it fits accordingly on mdpi(medium density) and xhdpi(extra high density) devices. What I like to do is use PhotoShop or another graphical editor and resize my assets so that they fit on whatever density devices I'm trying to target. I make sure to always use *WRAP_CONTENT* for my height and width attributes and never fixed values.

Also, if you do not include these scaled alternatives in your res/drawable folders..you're basically saying that you're relying on the system to scale them for you, which can be a gamble. So I always go with resizing my assets so that I include a version for all densities. The link you posed explains everything pretty well

Comment: Ya,but how i can find if the 40x40 is the right size??? And how i know my density phone and how this density can change my button?

Comment: Try to find your device on this list and see if the density is listed http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/. I resize my buttons in Photoshop or Gimp..on a canvas that is the same size as the resolution I'm targeting

Comment: So if my 40x40 button looks good on my testing device, which is hdpi..I'll create a canvas in PhotoShop that is the same resolution of the next phone/tablet that I'm trying to scale for..and then resize the button that way. This is just how I do it, however. Keep in mind that most devices shipped these days are of the hdpi density, so your button will most likely be scaled just fine for lower densities..you'll just have to include another version for tablets and such

Comment: So,for i draw a button what i should look is my device dimensions and after that if i wnat to make a new button for others devices i have to scalle button looking for dpi?

Comment: Yes, basically. Since most devices that are shipped these days are hdpi, you'll only have to worry about scaling your buttons/assets up. If you don't have Photoshop to do this, then try GIMP here http://www.gimp.org/downloads/